# facebook Check RFC 3986

Tags: facebook-oauth

When posting the following request

> `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?oauth_version="1.0"&oauth_nonce="5887e5b11904194f7d217e9b7f795d62"&oauth_timestamp="1317623602",&oauth_consumer_key="607197622"
>   &oauth_token="AQD8Y6xnKqRYThyLowBETEx5-fyr_cqVcmvItdnfgv01B24_WA0ykwRmkJgG6cyQgEJpyXQLIEauF0B24p8oqffoO-brGa2V1H9gASlAazKwOv65CvlbvGsEGd0Dk2VC58iiKGgB7xo7Rf4nL-V-G_buB_nNaHsyLHJJp-j2Rg9_4fmBmic74QrS1VIedU4W5-Sb2K-8oNh8a--mi9lIIyah#_=_"&oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1"&oauth_signature="96be7526390b287e7a32d"
>   &redirect_uri="https://apps.facebook.com/mymegha/"`

getting the following error

```js
{ "error": {
    "message": "Missing redirect_uri parameter.",
    "type": "OAuthException"
  }
}
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the double quotes around the parameters.

```
 access_token?oauth_version=1.0&...
```